# Invalid types in Delphi XE4 generic wrapper

Tags: delphi, generics

I want to use a wrapper around a `TDictionary<string,T>` for some reason. But when I try to iterate over the map by `for` the compiler says:

`[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(23): E2010 Incompatible types: 'T' and 'System.Generics.Collections.TPair<System.string,Unit1.TMyMapWrapper<T>.T>'`

How can I modify the generic type declaration to make a simple code like this compilable?

This is my simplified code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

implementation

uses
  Generics.Collections
  ;

type
  TMyMapWrapper<T> = class
    private
      fMap : TDictionary<string,T>;
    public
      procedure foo;
  end;

procedure TMyMapWrapper<T>.foo;
var
  item : T;
begin
  for item in fMap do
    ;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5):

If `X` is of type `TDictionary<A, B>`, then the enumerated items will be of type `TPair<A, B>`, not `B`.

```
var
  item: TPair<string, T>;
begin
  for item in fMap do // will compile
```

If you only want to enumerate the dictionary's values (of type `T`), use

```
var
  val: T;
begin
  for val in fMap.Values do // will compile
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate over the values of a dictionary you have to make that clear:

```
  for item in fMap.Values do
    ;
```

Otherwise you are iterating over the dictionary pairs.

Comment: Oh sh1t! I have forgotten the `values`!!! Thanks a lot! It is my fault.

Comment: @TheBitmanYou should accept one of the answers and upvote the ones you like.